# Hybris: FULL Indexing is success in solr cronjob log but few product are not coming?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

In log file Full-Indexing have not any error message. 
Cronjob log is showing success but few product are not coming.

> Any one tell me what is exact problem ?

Comment: If I run manually Indexing  Cronjob through backoffice  then it is working

Comment: Are there any common properties for the products that does not show? If you start with an empty index, does any products show? Could the objects have been added between the start of the indexing process and it finishing?

Comment: just few product are not came

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in Solr Server http://localhost:8983/solr whether your missing products are coming or not?

**Case 1 :** If Products are showing in Solr server

In that case might be due to some search filters, few products are not showing in storefront. Try to debug what exactly query is hitting to solr server. Have you added any custom filter condition in commerceSearchQueryPageableConverter chain ? Debug SearchFiltersPopulator as well.

**Case 2 :** Products are not showing in Solr server

In that case, you need to check your Full and Update Index Query.